# How to call Javascript function on PageLoad in MasterPage In ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to show a notification if the user is not authenticated using a jquery plugin but I don't know how to do this. It keeps saying the function isn't defined. I have to load the scripts on bottom of masterpa.ge I already tried so far. Also this code is on the masterpage.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowNoty", "ShowNoty('error','Accesso não autorizado.');", true);  
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
    else
    {

    } 
}
```

Js function

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $(document).ready(function ShowNoty(type, message) {
        var noty = new Noty({
            theme: 'bootstrap-v4',
            text: message,
            type: type,
            timeout: 3000,
            animation: {
                open: 'animated bounceInRight', // Animate.css class names
                close: 'animated bounceOutRight' // Animate.css class names
            },
            layout: 'topRight',
            onHover: function () {
                noty.Close();
            },
        }).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, do not get confused between back and front end here. You C# is checking authentication and then registering a script if they are not. So that is all fine.You jQuery is binding to two events which is pointless. Just bind to the ready and try that. I have not used Noty, but the code looks fine, remove the `on('load'` bind and try.

Comment: Just create your `function ShowNoty` and do not wrap it in `$(window).on('load'...` and `$(document).ready`.

Comment: it does not work still. I really don't know why it can't find the function on codebehind. If I do it in jquery it works like a charm

Comment: I found the problem, it seems the script was being executed inside the form only in the masterpage. All the script references are outside of the form tag on master page so on the page it didn't reach them outside of the form. Is there anyway to make it look on the whole page rather then only the form tag?